# cannot push git notes to remote

Tags: git, git-notes

For some reason I cannot push the notes from my local git repository to the remote repository.

`git log`, shows the notes after each commit, but if I perform:

```
git push origin refs/notes/*
```

I get

> Everything up-to-date

But notes are not really pushed. I cannot see them in gitblit, while for all other projects I can.

Is there anything I can do to solve or at least debug this issue?

Comment: If you're using a non-standard notes name space configuration, see https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/issues/366

Comment: Did you solve this @marinos-an?

Comment: @vburojevic I think this issue was the following. I had migrated from SVN using subgit, which adds all svn revisions as git commit notes. However when I tried to use `bfg` to remove history of big binaries, it removed my notes (This is an open bug of bfg).

Comment: @MarinosAn thx for response